# Tweak pandoc highlighting for C#

Tags: c#, markdown, pandoc

I use Pandoc for Markdown compiling. But it seems that the integrated syntax highlighter doesn't know about the `var` C# keyword and doesn't highlight it when compiled into PDF:

`pandoc foo.md -o foo.pdf`

Is there any way how to tweak the Pandoc syntax highlighter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some instructions for doing this at the end of the [README for highlighting-kate](https://github.com/jgm/highlighting-kate/).  Note that you'll have to recompile the library and pandoc, so this is only a good solution if you have a Haskell build environment set up and don't mind compiling pandoc from source.

In pandoc 1.12 (which I hope will be out this month), there will be an easy way to specify python "filters" that operate directly on the parsed document; so, for example, you could write a short filter that calls pygments to highlight code blocks.